# scribble: how to remove "WARNING no declared exporting libraries"

Tags: racket, scribble

I'm trying to use [`defproc`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/scribble/doc-forms.html#%28form._%28%28lib._scribble%2Fmanual..rkt%29._defproc%29%29) to format a function definition (**not** to document a library). The code below gets the formatting right, but prints an ugly warning to the console when I run Scribble:

```
#lang scribble/manual
@require[(for-label racket/contract)]

@defproc[(f [x integer?]) integer?]{
  The best @racket[f].
}
```

Running `scribble --html example.scrbl` prints:

```
example.scrbl:4:10: WARNING: no declared exporting libraries for definition
  in: f
```

Is there any way to use `defproc` for formatting, and remove the error message?

Comment: TFW you go to upvote a question and find out you already did...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. Add the optional argument `#:link-target? #f` to communicate your goal.

```
#lang scribble/manual
@require[(for-label racket/contract)]

@defproc[#:link-target? #f
         (f [x integer?]) integer?]{
  The best @racket[f].
}
```